# Issue with a simple app

Tags: java, android

I'm new in coding, and I was trying to make a simple app that make a subtraction from 2 variable, but when I click the button to calculate, the app crashes... Can someone help me finding the problem in the code? (Android Studio)

Here's the code:

```
package apps.ste.resto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static apps.ste.resto.R.id.risultato;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView importo;
TextView conto;
TextView risultato;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    TextView risultato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView importo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView conto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button bottone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bottone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result();
        }
    });
}

public void result(){
    float result = Float.parseFloat(importo.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(conto.getText().toString());
    risultato.setText(Float.toString(result));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You are calling result() method from within result() method, wouldn't that create infinite loop?? Also, please post logcat.

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: I can't post the error log, I don't use the emuletor because is very slow, and it takes 10m only to turn it on... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting null value for getText()..

SO you can try this :

```
public void result(){

   boolean digitsOnly1 = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(importo.getText()+"");
   boolean digitsOnly2 = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(conto.getText()+"");

   if(digitsOnly1 && digitsOnly2){
        float result = Float.parseFloat(importo.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(conto.getText().toString());
        risultato.setText(result+""));
   }else{
        risultato.setText("Please provide inputs");
   }

}
```